# Weld on Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, weblogic, cdi, weld

I am trying to run a application based on Weld, JPA2, Vaadin on Weblogic 10.3.

My problem is that Weld seems to register all Beans but they get not injected into my servlets.

Following log message is suspicious:

```
1433 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO  org.jboss.weld.environment.gwtdev.GwtDevHostedModeContainer  - Jetty detected, JSR-299 injection will be available in Servlets and Filters. Injection into Listeners is not supported.
30.08.2012 16:09:20 org.jboss.weld.environment.jetty.MortbayWeldServletHandler process
INFO: Cannot find matching WebApplicationContext, no default CDI support: use jetty-web.xml
```

Basically I followed this blog: http://jianmingli.com/wp/?p=4373 for the weld integration.

Probably I need to configure the beanmanager according http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5036 but I don't how to.

Does anyone have any ideas?

/Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

did you do these steps speechified in tutorial?

- You have to place beans.xml in src/META-INF. Place it in WEB-INF won't work.
- You have to create a weblogic.xml in WEB-INF directory and set wls:prefer-web-inf-classes to true. Otherwise, WEB-INF/lib jar files won't get loaded properly.

Weblogic is a wired App server! I'm using the version 12.1.1 and have many problems with CDI !

If reading that tutorial is for learning purposes I suggest not to use Weblogic, use Glassfish of jBoss AS instead.

[JBoss developer framework](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/examples/get-started/) has many great examples and tutorials in this scope.

Comment: I got beans.xml in both places and I got the classloading working. Unfortunately I have problems with classloading the other way around, when I set parent last. The company I work decided to take weblogic some time ago. Weblogic is crap, I know, especially 10.3.x. The app runs on top of JBoss 7 with no problems.

Comment: Yeah I totally understand you, I have exactly your problem! someone made completely wrong decision and we have to deal with problems.

Comment: And then comes ITIL in and you want to get out. They dont want to have different versions of app servers, so we will never pick up 12c, because our ERP requires 11g and that will run forever. So maybe I have to stick to good old JEE5.

Comment: I'm not a spring lover but another alternative would be Spring ;) it is really powerful and is just using servlet container and it has all other thing bundled inside itself.